# I get an error of the type when the variable is declared to have a function scope

Tags: java, scope, global-variables

Following is some function :

```
        jTextField1.setEnabled(false);
        jTextField2.setEnabled(false);
        jTextField3.setEnabled(false);
        jComboBox1.setEnabled(false);
        jComboBox2.setEnabled(false);
        String samplingRate = jTextField1.getText();
        String sampleSize = jTextField2.getText();
        String channels = jTextField3.getText();
        String endian = (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        String outputFormat = (String)jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();
        AudioFormat outputAudioFormat = new AudioFormat( Float.parseFloat(samplingRate) , Integer.parseInt(sampleSize) , Integer.parseInt(channels) , true , Boolean.parseBoolean(endian) );
        AudioInputStream newAIS;  // newAIS declared Here 
        try {
         newAIS = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(outputAudioFormat,  AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(originalFile) ) );
         // The above statement converts the data in the original file to the data filled by the user
        } catch( Exception exc ){
            System.out.println( exc );
          }
        String outLoc = null;
        JFileChooser saveLoc = new JFileChooser();
        int option = saveLoc.showSaveDialog(this);
        if( option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) 
            outLoc = saveLoc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        try {
        if( outputFormat == "AIFF" ) {
          AudioSystem.write(newAIS, AudioFileFormat.Type.AIFF, new File(outLoc) ); 
          // the above line gives an error saying that newAis might not have been intialized                  
        } else if( outputFormat == "WAVE") {
            AudioSystem.write(newAIS, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new File(outLoc) );
            // the above line gives an error saying that newAis might not have been intialized     
          } else if( outputFormat == "AU") {
              AudioSystem.write(newAIS, AudioFileFormat.Type.AU, new File(outLoc) );
              // the above line gives an error saying that newAis might not have been intialized     
            } else if( outputFormat == "SND") {
                AudioSystem.write(newAIS, AudioFileFormat.Type.SND, new File(outLoc) );
                // the above line gives an error saying that newAis might not have been intialized     
              }
        } catch( Exception exc ){
          }
```

In the above snippet i declare a variable `newAIS` of type `AudioInputStream`. *(12th statement from starting)* In the next statement the variable `newAIS` is intialized. When i reach the `if-else` part variable `newAIS` is said to be uninitialized by the IDE and it gives an error saying **newAis might not have been initialized** Why is it so ? The variable `newAIS` has function scope.

***On the other hand if i declare variable `newAIS` global , the IDE doesn't spot an error.***

Why does this happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's in *scope*, but it may not have been initialized - if an exception occurs, then instead of the variable being assigned a value, you're just printing out the exception and continuing. What value would you expect `newAIS` to have in that case?

Local variables are checked for definite assignment before being read, but instance / static variables aren't.

Note that if you *didn't* keep going in the fact of an exception, but instead threw another exception up to the caller, or just didn't catch it in the first place, or returned, it would be fine. It's not clear what exceptions you're really trying to handle - catching `Exception` is a bad practice in general.

You *could* just assign the variable a value to start with:

```
AudioInputStream newAIS = null;
```

... but do you *really* want to keep going if the assignment fails?

Also note that you're currently comparing strings using `==`, which is also a bad idea. This:

```
if (outputFormat == "AIFF")
```

should probably be:

```
if (outputFormat.equals("AIFF"))
```

Comment: and in case of global declaration of `newAIS`, why doesn't the IDE throw an error ?

Comment: @Suhail: Because as I said, only local variables are checked for definite assignment before being read. There's no way the compiler can know whether a variable has been assigned in some other method, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize the variable into try block. If initialization throws exception you just print it and continue. You should throw the exception in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It is because an exception might happen in `newAIS = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(...`, so newAIS never gets initialized.

You should do the following:

```
AudioInputStream newAIS = null;  // newAIS declared Here 
try {
   newAIS = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(outputAudioFormat, AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(originalFile) ) );

   } catch( Exception exc ){
         // handle the exception properly not just write something out!
}
```

You might want to return in the catch so you could avoid `NullPoiterException`.